# Update ShieldConfigurationExtension after action click

Tags: ios

Using the relatively new ManagedSettings API for iOS, I implemented custom UI for the shield that is displayed over an app that is blocked:

```
class ShieldConfigurationExtension: ShieldConfigurationDataSource {
  override func configuration(shielding application: Application) -> ShieldConfiguration {
    // Customize the shield as needed for applications.
    return ShieldConfiguration(
        backgroundBlurStyle: UIBlurEffect.Style.systemMaterialLight,
        backgroundColor: UIColor(red: 0.71, green: 0.66, blue: 0.98, alpha: 1.00),
      icon: UIImage(named: "doxoblocker"),
      title: ShieldConfiguration.Label(text: "Life is short.", color: .black),
      subtitle: ShieldConfiguration.Label(text: "But if you wanna use this app, let’s make sure to pay.", color: .black),
      primaryButtonLabel: ShieldConfiguration.Label(text: "Thanks!", color: .white),
      primaryButtonBackgroundColor: UIColor.black,
      secondaryButtonLabel: ShieldConfiguration.Label(text: "Break ", color: .black)
    )
}
```

And I have customized the code that changes what the buttons do upon execution:

```
class ShieldActionExtension: ShieldActionDelegate {

override func handle(action: ShieldAction, for application: ApplicationToken, completionHandler: @escaping (ShieldActionResponse) -> Void) {
    switch action {
        
    case .primaryButtonPressed:
        
        // CUSTOM ACTION ON PRESS }
```

My question is how can I update the UI of ShieldConfiguration in the first block I pasted when a click happens in primary button pressed?

The only solution I can think of is a custom hack where I inject a class upon click, but I'm not sure how that would be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the most common way to do this is using [app groups](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/configuring-app-groups). You add both the ShieldAction and ShieldConfiguration extensions to the same app group, so they can share data (though shared user defaults, for example).

Once the two extensions are in the same app group, you should be able to add data to the app group's shared container when the user clicks on the primary button, and then return the `.defer` response. This will redraw the shield, reading from the ShieldConfigurationDataSource again. You read the shared data in the ShieldConfiguration extension, and if it's been set you can change the shield title, subtitle, labels, etc.

Comment: Yes I had ended up doing this exactly

Answer (score 0):

Just to highlight a potential issue. Wasted some time at it.

I had an issue that ShieldActionDelegate methods were not called. Appeared to be - missed to change the Min Deployment iOS version for Extension.