# Data sharing between ShieldConfigurationExtension and ShieldActionExtension

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to share data between ShieldConfigurationExtension and ShieldActionExtension to update the shield after performing an action.
I created an app group, enabled it for both extensions and my main app. But when I'm writing data in ShieldConfigurationExtension I cannot get it in the ShieldActionExtension.

Here is how I do it:

```
// In ShieldConfigurationExtension
let sharedDefaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "your.app.group.identifier")
sharedDefaults?.set("yourData", forKey: "sharedKey")
sharedDefaults?.synchronize()

// In ShieldActionExtension
let sharedDefaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "your.app.group.identifier")
if let sharedData = sharedDefaults?.string(forKey: "sharedKey") {
    // Use sharedData in ShieldActionExtension
}
```

What is interesting writing data from my main app works and I can read it in both extensions.

I've tried to recreate the app group, but that didn't helped.

Comment: btw here is an answer where a person was able to do it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76775859/update-shieldconfigurationextension-after-action-click